# Tcl - SQLite - How to retrive a proper Tcl resultset

Tags: sqlite, tcl, row

I'm in my early stages while using SQlite with TCL, so forgive me my possibly humble question :).

Problem: Whenever I start a call like "select * from table" in TCL, i DO get the requested results. But, there is one problem. It has no Record delimiter like "\n", just a Space. The result therefore is just one list with "lindex 0".

I could circumvent this behaviour with the ".seperator ROW '\n'" option. Unfortunately it is not available in the TCL code, so
"sqlite3 .separator "\n"
just gives a "missing database" error, while this option works with the sqlite3.exe w.o. problems.
(Interestingly enough, the option "sqlite2 .mode tcl" works even in TCL)

How do I get the proper TCL results (like the "lindex of lindex" ones)?

Tried setting ".separator" with any thinkable approach in TCL to no avail.

Comment: What form of the `eval` command are you using to get the query results?

Comment: in TCL it is s.th. like [db eval "select * from table"].
The result is a one dimensional list with depth 0 (aka "1" :) ) It has all the rows in it, but as just one huge row. There is only a blank as row delimiter, making it just one large list.
If I try that in sqlite.exe, using a common separator like "\n", anything is fine. It is just TCL, that seems to not allow it :)

Comment: The docs show an example... [eval](https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#eva)  _You can also process the results of a query one row at a time by specifying the name of an array variable and a script following the SQL code._

Comment: You need to process the list of results N elements at a time where N is the number of columns being returned. But yeah, the other forms that give you a row at a time are easier to use.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. 
However, all not very promising. I have an inner blockage sort of, because SQLite already provides the feature, TCL just does not seem to allow me to use it ( .separator ).
I know, that Arrays are faster, but I would suspect a Memory Overhead. Since the Code should be general purpose, I would like to have it basic. Also it might get used in situations, the requirements from the source-db are not known at start. It should not be too cumbersome to code to still allow a massive "select * from table'. Thanks for the efforts guys!

Comment: Wait, are you using the sqlite3 package in a Tcl script, or are you calling the shell (sqlite3.exe) from Tcl? The `.separator` command is a for the *shell*, not the SQLite library.

Comment: @mark, yes, i somehow hoped, that TCL allows the use of the ".separator" (it should be default anyway in my opinion).
Why am I so stressing this thing? :)
Before, I have worked with several libraries for MS SQL server. They ALL deliver results for e.g. "select *from table" in the form:
{ { record 1 bla ...} {record 2 bla {} } {record 3 bla...} } 
while SQLite gives me:
{ record 1 bla.... record 2 bla {} record 3 bla... }
I'm close to saying "This makes no sense at all" :) and that even in a scenario, where the data-provider knows all the things to soothe the programmers needs :)

Comment: @mark. I will try out the example you've given below, trying to put the arrays in the eval-loop into a list of my described liking and see, what timing and memory-penalties it might show. If it is minor, I would go with that, but .... with a sad and bad feeling.
My goal is to provide a small tool TCL, that distinguishes between the use of 64 and 32 bit and in this scenario between the auto-selection of ms-sql and sqlite in a homgenious and transparent way. All calls always the same, that is. Therfore I have no way around my described "list in list" result. Thanks for your input n the sample.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [TDBC](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TdbcCmd/tdbc.htm) instead.

Comment: @shawn. Thanks for the hint, actually I did not try that, very good idea. Usually i do not favor the use of some sort of wrapper, since for me, an additional layer has always the penalty of overhead ( this comes from the belly, i can't help it :) ). In my case it could be beneficial, since it could keep me from preparing the direct results into a more generic form which would definitely be a misadvantage to do it in a not native language (TCL). I will try that. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @shawn, I tried it with tdbc::sqlite3 today and it gives what I wished for :). Works pretty fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the array example in the SQLite docs, here are a few other simple
ways to deal with the flat list that SQLite produces:

```
package require sqlite3

sqlite3 db1 :memory:
db1 nullvalue NULL

db1 eval {CREATE TABLE t1(a int, b text)}

db1 eval {INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,'hello')}
db1 eval {INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,'goodbye')}
db1 eval {INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(3,'howdy!')}
set x [db1 eval {SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY a}]

puts $x
>1 hello 2 goodbye 3 howdy!

foreach {a b} $x {
  puts "$a | $b"
}
>1 | hello  
>2 | goodbye
>3 | howdy!

foreach {a b} $x {
  set d [dict set d $a $b]
}
puts $d
>1 hello 2 goodbye 3 howdy!

for {set i 1} {$i < 4} {incr i} {
  puts [dict get $d $i]
}
>hello
>goodbye
>howdy!
```

These are sometimes handy for short or narrow resultsets.

Comment: You don't need a separate `foreach` when you can do `db1 eval {SELECT * from t1 order by a} ary {puts "$ary(a) | $ary(b)"}` (with the column names are listed in `$ary(*)`).

Comment: @DonalFellows: Yes, that approach is shown in the SQLite docs, so I didn't include it here.